# How and where can I import a common SCSS files, so that it gets available in every scss files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have scss files that use variables for colors. like -

```
.label-primary, .badge-primary {
  background-color: $navy;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.label-success, .badge-success {
  background-color: $blue;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}

.label-warning, .badge-warning {
  background-color: $yellow;
  color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

These variables are defined in `variables.scss` file

I have already @imported `@import "base/variables";` in application.css.scss file.

```
// Variables, Mixins
@import "base/variables";
@import "base/mixins";
```

but still it doesnt loads in other scss files and throws error `Sass::SyntaxError: Undefined variable: "$navy".` where trying to precompile in production.

I have to explicitely `@import "base/variables";` in every scss file on the top. there are 35 files.

How can i define this variable.scss file in just one place so that its loaded in every scss file?

```
NOTE: I am using rails-api gem and the application is API only. I have tweaked a bit to make some views on this application.
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `sprockets-sass` gem ? It works great with Sprockets 2.x and 3.x with both SCSS and SASS files.

And it does exactly what you need :D